# Navigation Bar and Title in Xcode Simulator

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

I can't get the Navigation Bar Items to show in the app simulator using Xcode 7.2.1.

I have my Navigation Controller and my Main Scene. My main scene has a Navigation Item set.

This is my setup:

[image: My Setup]

But when I run the simulator, there's no title bar. Really frustrating. I've tried changing the status bar and top bar menu options, but to no avail. Any idea how to get them to appear using the Xcode GUI and not programatically?

Comment: Bar Button Items Matt?

Comment: I just wondered if you have added a navigation item first of all before adding the bar button item.

Comment: Hi @Tom I can drag Bar Button Items to the left or right areas of next to the title - they appear in Xcode, but not in the simulator. Does that clarify?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. They appear in my simulator, unfortunately I can't recreate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you accidentally cleared the "Shows Navigation Bar" setting in the Navigation Controller itself?

[image]

Comment: Afraid not, that's the only one that is checked.

Comment: Do the views you added to Main Scene all show up, though? Is it just the nav bar that is missing?

Comment: Because IB is so easy to do this with, my suggestion is to add an empty view controller to the storyboard, remove the root view controller connection to Main Scene, and connect it to the new view controller. Assign the new view controller a title, and run the app in the simulator. Does the title appear?

Comment: We're getting somewhere! I did these steps and it worked - but I've realized what has been going on. In my AppDelegate I have some code to change the initial view controller. E.g. If the user has no "goal" they are working toward in my goal app, it immediately loads the "add a goal" view. I guess my task now is to move this code to the Nav Controller. Is that what you'd suggest?

Comment: Oh, you were resetting AppDelegate's rootViewController or resetting the rootViewController of your NavigationController?

Comment: Ignore my last comment. When you say you immediately load the add a goal view, how do you do so? In code? With [self presentViewController:...]?

Comment: self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AddGoal")
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104807/discussion-between-matt-and-matt-lewin).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting your current Navigation Controller in Storyboard and re-embedding your controller in it (or dragging a new Navigation Controller out and setting its default controller by control-dragging to your VC?)

Comment: it did work! But I've realized what has been going on. In my AppDelegate I have some code to change the initial view controller. E.g. If the user has no "goal" they are working toward in my goal app, it immediately loads the "add a goal" view. When I commented out this code, it worked. My task now is to move this code to the Nav Controller.

Comment: Glad it worked. As a suggestion, don't subclass your Nav Controller. Instead put that logic into viewDidLoad of your firstViewController and from there set the viewControllers array of the navController as needed.